# WSO2 4.1.0 HA mode :: Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /appName/1.0/api/auth/signin

Tags: wso2-api-manager, high-availability

We have WSO2 HA setup on our Linux based internal servers (xx.xx.xx.67 & xx.xx.xx.68) where one mode is running fine and other one always returns 404 with Invalid URL error. Both the nodes are pointed to a common MySQL DB and we have the **/4.1.0/repository/deployment/server** pointed to a common **/nfs_share** (available on both the servers where changes on one server automatically reflects on the other server) for which a soft link is created (**/4.1.0/repository/deployment/server** -> **/nfs_share/server**).

Mode in deployment.toml:

```
[server]
hostname = "xx.xx.xx.68"

mode = "ha" #single or ha

#offset=0
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.78:3306/wso2_apim_db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;requireSSL=false"
username = "XXXX"
password = "XXXX
driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.78:3306/wso2_shared_db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;requireSSL=false"
username = "xxxx"
password = "xxxx"
driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://localhost:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8021"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
auth_token = ""

[apim.jwt]
enable = true

[apim.oauth_config]
enable_outbound_auth_header = true

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://xx.xx.xx.68:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[oauth.grant_type.token_exchange]
enable = true
allow_refresh_tokens = true
iat_validity_period = "1h"

[transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
HostnameVerifier = "AllowAll"

[clustering]
membership_scheme = "wka"
domain = "wso2.am.domain"
local_member_host = "xx.xx.xx.68"
local_member_port = 4500
members = ["xx.xx.xx.67:4500","xx.xx.xx.68:4500"]
shutdown_hook_enable = false
logging_type = "log4j"
```

Response from Postman:

```
{
    "code": "404",
    "type": "Status report",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "description": "The requested resource is not available."
}
```

Error in /4.1.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-08-16 18:49:43,776]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /appName/1.0/api/auth/signin, HEALTH CHECK URL = /appName/1.0/api/auth/signin
```

Tried with single mode which works absolutely fine and same setup not working if the mode is changed to HA. We have tried the setup multiple times but nothing works. To add-on we had a recent migration from 3.2.0 to 4.1.0. Same setup works with 3.2.0 but does not work with 4.1.0. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)